# Get value from selected row in WPF Datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a DataGrid in my WPF projects

[image]

As you can see i'm able to select a row. I've made a double click method where i get the selected row. i want get just the ID part of that row.
This is how my method looks like

[image]

```
private void Row_DoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridRow = sender as DataGridRow;
}
```

How to I just get the cell where I put the ID in it?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: You can not get the `DataGridRow` cell value.

Comment: Please post your code - as code - in the question itself

Comment: I assume you have some Data bound on your grid. If i am right try the following:  (row.Item as MyBoundObject).Id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are showing both XAML and cs code then only we can find the proper solution. Now I am assuming that you are displaying the contents by using binding from an observable collection of any class type. So you can easily get the ID field by,

```
private void Row_DoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    ClassName classObj = dataGridName.SelectedItem as ClassName;
    string id = classObj.ID;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is the code I used to get the ID of the double clicked row. I used an exploit of the double click (When you double click a row, you also select it). In my case, the column containing the id was the first (Row[0])

```
    private void Row_DoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        DataRowView dataRowView = (DataRowView)yourDataGridView.SelectedItem;
        int ID = Convert.ToInt32(dataRowView.Row[0]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using **Data Binding** from a Class object list you have to get the row like this

```
Your_Class row = SelectedStudents.SelectedItem as Your_Class;
```